# SQL - Empty or Null fields

Tags: sql-server-2008

I trying to check for null values or empty columns.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE  myColumn IS NULL OR myColumn = ' ';
```

The thing is, I want to include few tables (myTable1, myTable2, myTable3)
in the same query and avoid the need to specify a column name (myColumn)
so the query is generic as possible returning the empty or null column names in few tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to include the names, if you want to simplify the expression, you can use 
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE  Coalesce(myColumn,'') = ''

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @col   VARCHAR(255),
        @table VARCHAR(255),
        @cmd   VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE getinfo CURSOR FOR
  SELECT t.name,
         c.name
  FROM   sys.tables t
         JOIN sys.columns c
           ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
  WHERE  t.Name IN ( 'table-1', 'table-2' )

--WHERE  t.Name IN (provide your TABLE list)
OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo INTO @table, @col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      SELECT @cmd = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT top 1 * FROM ' + @table
                    + ' WHERE (' + @col + ' IS NULL or ' + @col
                    + '='''')) BEGIN print ''tablename=''+'''
                    + @table + '''+''  column name=''+''' + @col
                    + ''' end'

      --PRINT @cmd

      EXEC(@cmd)
      FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo INTO @table, @col
  END

CLOSE getinfo

DEALLOCATE getinfo
```

Comment: Thanks for that Parthiban. I have tried to put in a list of tables names under WHERE  t.Name IN (table1, table2, table3) and got an error saying 'Invalid column name 'table1'.' Once trying to use the single table decleation Where t.name = 'table1' it works fine...any way around this ?

Comment: Could you please tell me on which format you have used in the IN clause. I mean the values you have given should be within single quotes.

Comment: 2008 R2 SQL Management Suite

Comment: I have updated the code. Please try now. It is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Parthiban, it seems to be running OK now but I'm getting a 'Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.' message..Hard to tell whether it finishes the query.

Comment: I don't get any errors. We didn't convert any values from varchar to numeric in this Code. The table name and column name are the inputs we used in this TSQL. Have you done any changes in this code, if so could you please share that so that we can analyse.

Comment: I have to look into it again. It is strange.